How to build an SQL identifier that contains underscores, using Postgresql psql \set variables?
PG 14.11
This works perfectly:
CDSLBXW=# \set sch public
CDSLBXW=# \set tbl job_history
CDSLBXW=# \set fld job_id
CDSLBXW=# CREATE INDEX blarge ON :sch.:tbl (:fld);
CREATE INDEX

However, I do not want an index named "blarge".  The goal is to build a meaningful index name from the table and field names, but underscores cause it to fail:
CDSLBXW=# CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS tmpidx_:tbl_:fld ON :sch.:tbl (:fld);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS tmpidx_:tbl_job_id O...

                                                   ^

In bash, you'd use curly braces to delimit the variable names, but those aren't available in psql.
What to do?
EDIT: SELECT format() ... \gexec works, but I was hoping for something more direct.
SELECT format('CREATE INDEX tmpidx_%2$I_%3$I ON %1$I.%2$I (%3$I);', 
              :'sch', :'tbl', :'fld') \gexec


In this case, you can take help of PL/pgSQL to dynamically generate the SQL Statement.
You can use below code
--set the variables 
\set sch public
\set tbl job_history
\set fld job_id

-- Create index using the variables
DO $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS %I ON %I.%I (%I) WITH (fillfactor=100);', :sch || '_' || :tbl || '_' || :fld || '_idx', :sch, :tbl, :fld);
END $$;

Adjust the variables as per your need.

SELECT format('CREATE ...', ....) \gexec works just as well, without DO.  I was hoping for something more direct.
